# Regular expression to search in a specific file sheet

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to use regular expressions in VBA to search in a specific file sheet.

I am trying to filter certain data.

I believe there is an issue with how to set my worksheet to the required value.

```
Dim RE As Object
Dim LSearchRow As Long
Dim LCopyToRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Values")

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
RE.Pattern = "(T04)"
RE.Ignorecase = True

LSearchRow = 5 'Start search in row 5
LCopyToRow = 3 'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)

While Len(Cells(LSearchRow, "A").Value) > 0

    If RE.test(Cells(LSearchRow, "H").Value) Then

        'i believe this is the problem area, If i use active.Rows there isnt an issue
        ws.Rows(LSearchRow).Copy Sheets("Filtered T04").Rows(LCopyToRow)

        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1 'Move counter to next row
    End If

    LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

Range("A3").Select 'Position on cell A3
MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Comment: First things first: Remove the `On Error GoTo` to further define ***where*** (which line) your error occurs.

Comment: @Jvdv i have a range issue. Error 9

Comment: Check your sheet name is correct

Comment: `While Len(Cells(LSearchRow, "A").Value) > 0` > This would be using the activesheet for instance, so would `If RE.test(Cells(LSearchRow, "H").Value) Then` and `Range("A3").Select` too. If your intention was to use `ws` then simply add `ws.` in front.

Comment: @TimWilliams i though that there was an issue with the name of my sheet but it is correct

Comment: @jvdv yes i was testing for activesheet how do handle this issue?

Comment: @JvdV just to be clear, Where should i try to put my ws because i intent to set my worksheet as "values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly refer to your set `ws`. Lines like:

```
While Len(Cells(LSearchRow, "A").Value) > 0
```

Will refer to the currently `ActiveSheet`. So, my guess is that you want to use the below:

```html
Sub Test()
Dim RE As Object
Dim LSearchRow As Long
Dim LCopyToRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Values")

'On Error GoTo Err_Execute

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
RE.Pattern = "(T04)"
RE.Ignorecase = True

LSearchRow = 5 'Start search in row 5
LCopyToRow = 3 'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)

While Len(ws.Cells(LSearchRow, "A").Value) > 0

 If RE.Test(ws.Cells(LSearchRow, "H").Value) Then
     ws.Rows(LSearchRow).Copy Sheets("Filtered T04").Rows(LCopyToRow) 'i believe this is the problem area, If i use active.Rows there isnt an issue
     LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1 'Move counter to next row
 End If

 LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

ws.Range("A3").Select 'Position on cell A3
MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub

'Err_Execute:
'MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

The above code runs/works, but make sure you haven't made an error in naming your `ws` variable. If you still hit an error please let us know what line it occurs.

**Note:** Just one thing I would do in your case is look into `AutoFilter` as an alternative to `RegEx` since you don't really use a regular expression but rather need to know if a substring exists in a cell. This would eliminate the need of iteration

Comment: thanks to your help, there is no longer an issue on the loop how ever there is an issue on the  "ws.Range("A3").Select" they give me a 1004 error

Comment: @RohitRai, that is (probably) because your activesheet is **not** `ws`.... therefor the error 1004 is thrown. Why do you intend to use `.Select`? Best is to avoid this.